# Why did Black allow White to capture en passant two times in a row?

Tags: analysis, tactics, positional-play, en-passant

I read about this game on Tim Krabbe’s website and found it on [chessgames.com](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1086879). I am severely confused by Black’s 30th and 31st moves.

```
[Title "Sergey Gennadyevich Kudrin-Rudy C Douven, GMA Baleares op, Palma de Mallorca Spain, 12/1989"]
[startply "59"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 c6 2. d4 d5 3. Nc3 dxe4 4. Nxe4 Bf5 5. Ng3 Bg6 6. h4 h6 7. Nf3 Nd7 8. h5 Bh7 9. Bd3 Bxd3 10. Qxd3 e6 11. Bf4 Qa5+ 12. Bd2 Qc7 13. O-O-O Ngf6 14. Ne4 O-O-O 15. g3 Nxe4 16. Qxe4 Nf6 17. Qe2 Bd6 18. Ne5 c5 19. Rh4 Bxe5 20. dxe5 Nd7  21. Rg4 Rhg8 22. Re1 Qc6 23. Qe4 Nb8 24. Rf4 Rd7 25. Qh7 Rgd8 26. Ba5 b6 27. Bc3  Qd5 28. b3 b5 29. Kb1 b4 30. Bb2 f5 31. exf6 g5 32. hxg6 Rxh7 33. gxh7 e5 34. Rxe5 Qf7 35. Re7 Qf8 36. f7 Qxe7 37. f8=Q Rxf8 38. Rxf8+ Qxf8 39. h8=Q Qxh8 40. Bxh8 h5 41. Kc1 Kd7 42. Kd2 Ke6 43. Ke3 Kf5 44. f3 Nd7 45. Kd3 Nb6 46. Bg7 a5 47. Bf8 Nd7 48. Bd6 Ke6 49. Bc7 Kd5 50. c4+ bxc3 51. Kxc3
```

Why would Black let White capture en passant two times in a row and gain two very powerful passed pawns? Sure, the queen gets nabbed, but I just don’t think that it’s a good idea. What good is nabbing one queen when two more might soon pop up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point was to win the queen. Yes, White gets two passed pawns, but a passed pawn won't necessarily get to be promoted.

Sure it happened in the game, but that's not really the point here.